# When is buckshot preferable to slugs with shotguns in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

In what situations is it better to use buckshot than slugs with shotguns in Battlefield 3?

In close quarters battles, 6/11 pellets need to hit for a 1 hit kill… and that falls off quickly, to the point where at even moderate distances it takes 3 or 4 shells to kill an opponent.

Slugs, however, are guaranteed one hit kill in close quarters, and still deal an appreciable amount of damage at range.

Moreover, even in close quarters, I feel like I get more killing hits with slugs than with shot.

So: when does it make sense to use buckshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, a small rundown on `buckshot pellets` per shotgun vs `slug rounds` per shotgun as seen on wikia ([Buckshot](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/12_Gauge_Buckshot) / [Slugs](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/12_Gauge_Slugs)):

```
Buckshot Pellets  /  Shotgun  /  Damage based on Distance
----------------------------------------------------------
 11 pellets          SPAS-12       18.0 - 6.0 / pellet
 9 pellets           SAIGA12K      18.0 - 6.0 / pellet
 9 pellets           DAO-12        18.0 - 6.0 / pellet
 10 pellets          M1014         18.0 - 6.0 / pellet
 12 pellets          870MCS        18.0 - 6.0 / pellet
 7 pellets           USAS-12       18.0 - 6.0 / pellet
 8 pellets           MK3A1         18.0 - 6.0 / pellet
 12 pellets          M26 MASS      18.0 - 6.0 / pellet

// Headshot Bonus : 2.40x

 Slug Rounds      /  Shotgun  /  Damage based on Distance
----------------------------------------------------------
  1 round            SPAS-12       100 - 40 (pump-action)
  1 round            SAIGA12K      75 - 37.5 (semi-automatic/auto)
  1 round            DAO-12        75 - 37.5 (semi-automatic/auto)
  1 round            M1014         75 - 37.5 (semi-automatic/auto)
  1 round            870MCS        100 - 40 (pump-action)
  1 round            USAS-12       75 - 37.5 (semi-automatic/auto)
  1 round            MK3A1         75 - 37.5 (semi-automatic/auto)
  1 round            M26 MASS      100 - 40 (pump-action)

// Headshot Bonus : Insta-kill?
```

That being said, in my opinion, in close quarters when your reticle is mainly on the target when you're using buckshot (especially on the area above the waist), its usually a instant-kill for me, and I'm not even aiming the weapon.

But if I chose to aim, or have my reticle generally focused on the enemy torso at close range, I would be able to also instantly kill someone at close range.

*From your question, however, it is also debatable on your definition of **"close range"**, which is usually 25metres and below in-game (for me).*

I would also -- if given the limited choices of a **buckshot** and **slug** shotgun only in the entire game -- choose the:

`Slug` for a long range engagement such as a **long-reaching room** or a **wide area**, because you can at least aim and be guaranteed to kill something in here.

`Buckshot` for **tight corners** and **small rooms** within 25m because its a confirmed kill usually at such low ranges.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: This. Hip-firing with slugs is significantly less effective than with buckshot. And hip-firing is necessary when surprised.